# facebook self.graph.put_object

Tags: python, facebook

I using the Python SDK (http://github.com/facebook/python-sdk/) with Google app engine.

I can post message on user wall with the self.graph.put_object function while the user is online.

How do post a message to user wall directly from the server even the user is offline?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you know how to kick the work off and just need the calls to authenticate for the user.

Your facebook app must request extended permissions from the user.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions

offline_access

> Enables your application to perform
>   authorized requests on behalf of the
>   user at any time. By default, most
>   access tokens expire after a short
>   time period to ensure applications
>   only make requests on behalf of the
>   user when the are actively using the
>   application. This permission makes the
>   access token returned by our OAuth
>   endpoint long-lived. NOTE: If you have
>   requested the publish_stream
>   permission, you can publish content to
>   a user's feed at any time, without
>   requiring offline_access.

Once you have done this the oauth_access_token returned from Facebook is an offline_access token and can be used anytime until the user revokes your app access or extended permission.